# Can a WinPhone Xamarin app be developed from Windows 10 Home

Tags: xamarin, windows-phone-8.1, xamarin.forms, hyper-v

I am trying to build and run the WinPhone project created from the default Blank App multi-project template for Xamarin.Forms Portable but I'm getting an error. The error refers to Hyper-V being needed for the WinPhone emulator. I do not have access to Hyper-V because I'm running Windows 10 Home edition.

My questions is this: is it even possible to develop an app that targets windows phones from a Windows Home computer? My thoughts were maybe I could emulate using something other than Hyper-V but I'm not sure where to start, or if I would hit other road-blocks.

In response to the other question related to this one, I'm specifically interested in windows 10 home edition, while the other post relates to windows 8. I'd like to know about possible solutions which may not have applied when the other question was asked 3 years ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hyper-V [cannot](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyperv_on_windows/quick_start/walkthrough_compatibility) be installed in Windows 10 Home version.

The Windows Phone emulator won't run.

You could develop the application but can only test on a real device.